# ccxt OKEx placing orders

Tags: python, ccxt

I placed DEMO order on OKEx with amount 246 and price 0.46. When I looked on site, order amount was more than 11k:[image]

I fetched info about order:

```
{'info': {'accFillSz': '0', 'avgPx': '', 'cTime': '1652262833825', 'category': 'normal', 'ccy': '', 'clOrdId': 'e847386590ce4dBCc812b22b16d7807c', 'fee': '0', 'feeCcy': 'USDT', 'fillPx': '', 'fillSz': '0', 'fillTime': '', 'instId': 'XRP-USDT-SWAP', 'instType': 'SWAP', 'lever': '1', 'ordId': '444557778278035458', 'ordType': 'limit', 'pnl': '0', 'posSide': 'long', 'px': '0.45693', 'rebate': '0', 'rebateCcy': 'USDT', 'side': 'buy', 'slOrdPx': '-1', 'slTriggerPx': '0.44779', 'slTriggerPxType': 'mark', 'source': '', 'state': 'live', 'sz': '246', 'tag': '', 'tdMode': 'isolated', 'tgtCcy': '', 'tpOrdPx': '-1', 'tpTriggerPx': '0.46606', 'tpTriggerPxType': 'mark', 'tradeId': '', 'uTime': '1652262833825'}, 'id': '444557778278035458', 'clientOrderId': 'e847386590ce4dBCc812b22b16d7807c', 'timestamp': 1652262833825, 'datetime': '2022-05-11T09:53:53.825Z', 'lastTradeTimestamp': None, 'symbol': 'XRP/USDT:USDT', 'type': 'limit', 'timeInForce': None, 'postOnly': None, 'side': 'buy', 'price': 0.45693, 'stopPrice': 0.44779, 'average': None, 'cost': 0.0, 'amount': 246.0, 'filled': 0.0, 'remaining': 246.0, 'status': 'open', 'fee': {'cost': 0.0, 'currency': 'USDT'}, 'trades': [], 'fees': [{'cost': 0.0, 'currency': 'USDT'}]}
```

and amount is 246.

Here is my code:

```py
exchange = ccxt.okx(
    {
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'secret': API_SECRET,
        'password': API_PASSPHRASE,
        'options': {
            'defaultType': 'swap'
        },
        'headers': {
            'x-simulated-trading': '1'
        }
}

exchange.load_markets()
market = exchange.market(PAIR)
params = {
    'tdMode': 'isolated',
    'posSide': 'long',
    'instId': market['id'],
    'side': 'buy',
    'sz': 246,
    'tpOrdPx': '-1',
    'slOrdPx': '-1',
    'tpTriggerPx': str(take_profit),
    'slTriggerPx': str(stop_loss),
    'tpTriggerPxType': 'mark',
    'slTriggerPxType': 'mark',
}
order = exchange.create_order(
    f"{PAIR}", ORDER_TYPE, 'buy', summa, price, params=params)
info = exchange.fetch_order(order['id'], PAIR)
print(info)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you can only buy multiples of 100 of XRP as you can see in the screenshot below so you can only buy 200 or 300 and not 246.

[image]

Secondly, it looks like there's a multiplier of 100 being applied in the api where 1 = 100 XRP. I was able to deduce this by entering 24,600 XRP which gives you around $11k that you mentioned.

In your case, if you were to buy 200 or 300 XRP, you would need to enter 2 or 3 as an amount in the api request.

[image]

Comment: I fetched info about market (https://pastebin.com/rfX1uze9)
Strange why contract size is 100, and lever 75

Comment: sorry whats your question exactly? also if my answer solved your problem can you accept it please?

Comment: Sadly, but not. Not solved. I tried all, and result is same. Maybe is there possible to change multiplying in market, or something else. Idk...

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do exactly? Can you clarify the problem as I don't see what it is?

Comment: I think I know solution. U are right. I'll try, and flag answer if helped. So, I need to divide my amount by lot size multiplied by open price, then round amount.